# How to derive orbital velocity without assuming direction

Tags: orbital-motion

In the usual derivation of orbital velocity at height $r$ we set centripetal acceleration equal to acceleration caused by gravity to get $\frac{v^2 }{r}=\gamma \frac{M}{r^2 }$ and get $v=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma M}{r}}$. Here $\gamma$ is the gravitational constant and $M$ is the mass of Earth.

However, this derivation assumes in using the formula for centripetal acceleration that $v$ is perpendicular to $r$. From this, it becomes unclear how the direction of $v$ affects the orbit or, indeed, whether there will be an orbit at all if the direction is not perpendicular to $r$.

Is there a way to derive orbital velocity without making this assumption? Furthermore, am I right in saying that if the limit velocity $v=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma M}{r}}$ is not perpendicular to $r$, the body will at some point hit the Earth? We are assuming $r$ to be the radius of Earth and launching from the surface of the Earth.

Comment: If the orbit is not circular the velocity will change along the orbit, both in direction and magnitude. So what "orbital velocity" are you trying to calculate? At a given point on the orbit?

Comment: Good question. I guess I was thinking about the minimum initial velocity required to get into any orbit that doesn't crash back to Earth, without having to assume perpendicularity. I assumed it would depend on direction since $v=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma M}{r}}$ clearly doesn't work if it's pointed radially outwards, or even at a slightly different angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orbital velocity can be calculated using conservation of energy. The total energy is the sum of the potential energy and the kinetic energy, and total energy is conserved. Since the potential energy is $-GMm/r$ we can calculate how the kinetic energy changes as $r$ increases and decreases.

When we do this for an orbiting particle we end up with the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation):

$$ v^2 = GM\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a} \right) $$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis of the orbit. For a circular orbit the semi-major axis is equal to the orbital radius $r$ and the equation reduces to the one you know:

$$ v^2 = GM\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{r} \right) = \frac{GM}{r} $$